# spring boot 2.7.0 doesn't expose http.server.request metrics

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-properties, spring-actuator

I'm using Spring boot 2.7.0 and I'm trying to expose the http.server.request metrics so I can scrape it in Prometheus but it's not working.
My application.yml properties look like this:

```
management:
    endpoint:
        health:
            probes:
                enabled: true
            show-details: always
    endpoints:
        web:
            exposure:
                include: '*'

    health:
        livenessState:
            enabled: true
        readinessState:
            enabled: true
    metrics:
        tags:
            application: ${spring.application.name}
        distribution:
            percentiles-histogram:
                http:
                    server:
                        requests: true
```

And I have the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

but in `/actuator/metrics` endpoint I can't see anything about http.server.request metrics.

```
{
  "names": [
    "application.ready.time",
    "application.started.time",
    "disk.free",
    "disk.total",
    "executor.active",
    "executor.completed",
    "executor.pool.core",
    "executor.pool.max",
    "executor.pool.size",
    "executor.queue.remaining",
    "executor.queued",
    "hikaricp.connections",
    "hikaricp.connections.acquire",
    "hikaricp.connections.active",
    "hikaricp.connections.creation",
    "hikaricp.connections.idle",
    "hikaricp.connections.max",
    "hikaricp.connections.min",
    "hikaricp.connections.pending",
    "hikaricp.connections.timeout",
    "hikaricp.connections.usage",
    "jdbc.connections.active",
    "jdbc.connections.idle",
    "jdbc.connections.max",
    "jdbc.connections.min",
    "jvm.buffer.count",
    "jvm.buffer.memory.used",
    "jvm.buffer.total.capacity",
    "jvm.classes.loaded",
    "jvm.classes.unloaded",
    "jvm.gc.live.data.size",
    "jvm.gc.max.data.size",
    "jvm.gc.memory.allocated",
    "jvm.gc.memory.promoted",
    "jvm.gc.overhead",
    "jvm.gc.pause",
    "jvm.memory.committed",
    "jvm.memory.max",
    "jvm.memory.usage.after.gc",
    "jvm.memory.used",
    "jvm.threads.daemon",
    "jvm.threads.live",
    "jvm.threads.peak",
    "jvm.threads.states",
    "logback.events",
    "process.cpu.usage",
    "process.start.time",
    "process.uptime",
    "resilience4j.circuitbreaker.buffered.calls",
    "resilience4j.circuitbreaker.calls",
    "resilience4j.circuitbreaker.failure.rate",
    "resilience4j.circuitbreaker.not.permitted.calls",
    "resilience4j.circuitbreaker.slow.call.rate",
    "resilience4j.circuitbreaker.slow.calls",
    "resilience4j.circuitbreaker.state",
    "system.cpu.count",
    "system.cpu.usage",
    "tomcat.sessions.active.current",
    "tomcat.sessions.active.max",
    "tomcat.sessions.alive.max",
    "tomcat.sessions.created",
    "tomcat.sessions.expired",
    "tomcat.sessions.rejected"
  ]
}
```

My teammates were able to fix this problem by downgrading the spring boot version to 2.3.7.release but I'm not very fond of that. Is there any other way to expose these metrics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/31150) with the 2.7.0 spring boot version. Upgrade to 2.7.1